# creditcard payment implementation in Android application

Tags: android, credit-card, payment-processing

I want to implement credit card payment process in my android application. There is a form in my application. User will enter his card information and on submission the service will verify and accept or reject the card. I have no idea if there is any API or a tutorial available in android. Please help me if someone knows how to do that.

//Zeeshan

Comment: This depends entirely on the card processing service you are using

Comment: i have no idea if there is any card processing service? Do you know any service? i can check that ...

Comment: You are going to have to contract with a company that provides card processing services, and talk to their server in whatever manner they specify.

Answer (score 1):

I would look for any type of REST or web-based API. Here's for example [some of the vendors](http://www.west-wind.com/westwindwebstore/docs/_1400QYNFF.htm) providing such APIs. Then, after you harvest information from the form you generate call using something like HttpClient to such API and you can be sophisticated enough to make it appear as call is coming from the desktop browser (if it is a requirement). Then you capture a response, parse it and present to the user